# django rest framework deserializing german characters not working

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-rest-framework

I have a JSON string like so:

```
u'{"repeat_password":"password","password":"password","username":"üääöp","email":"püäöö@email.com"}'
```

and am running it through the following:

```
def deserialization_helper(json):
    stream = StringIO(unicode(json))
    return JSONParser().parse(stream)
#stuff...
serializer = ValidationSerializer(data=deserialization_helper(request.DATA['data']))
```

However I seem to be getting the following exception, but only for german characters, if I use plain english characters it seems to work fine.

```
u'JSON parse error - \\'ascii\\' codec can\\'t encode characters in position 64-67: ordinal not in range(128)'
```

I've narrowed it down to the following line

```
JSONParser().parse(stream)
```

but can't seem to figure out a way for it to happily accept both english and german characters.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Try to put this code in your settings.py

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the source of the `JSONParser` ([`parsers.py`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/parsers.py)):

```
def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
    """
    Parses the incoming bytestream as JSON and returns the resulting data.
    """
    parser_context = parser_context or {}
    encoding = parser_context.get('encoding', settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)

    try:
        data = stream.read().decode(encoding)
        return json.loads(data)
    except ValueError as exc:
        raise ParseError('JSON parse error - %s' % six.text_type(exc))
```

We see that Django-Rest-Framework expects a *byte* stream which it decodes with the Django `DEFAULT_CHARSET` (which is UTF-8 at most times).

Without knowing more it's difficult to suggest a solution:

- `request.DATA` is already parsed by the DRF parsers, so when all is pure JSON there is no reason to re-parse.
- in the case you use form-encoding or the attribute `data` is a string with JSON content, you could use `force_bytes` to make bytes of it, or use `json.loads` directly (which accepts `unicode`).